# Recursive lsearch in exim

Tags: exim, exim4

I have the following router in my `exim.conf`:

```
my_redirect_router:
driver = redirect
data = ${lookup{$local_part@$domain}lsearch{/etc/exim/file}}
```

The `/etc/exim/file` used by lsearch has the following lines:

```
asdfqwerty@domain.com: asdf-qwerty@domain.com
asdf-qwerty@domain.com: abc@domain1.com,def@domain2.com,ghi@domain3.com
```

In the past, when an email is sent to `asdfqwerty@domain.com`, exim would be able to redirect to `asdf-qwerty@domain.com`, for which exim would then forward the email to the emails listed in the expansion. With the exim 4.89 that I have installed, this "recursive" lsearch expansion does not work anymore. When it receives mail for asdfqwerty@domain.com, it returns this error:

```
** asdf-qwerty@domain.com <asdfqwerty@domain.com>: Unknown user
```

I haven't changed my `exim.conf` file in 5+ years. What should I do to get this behavior again? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Run a debug session using the -bt switch and see what it gives you:

```
exim -d -bt asdf-qwerty@domain.com
```

It should show you where the lookup is failing.